# Dynamic Table Creation in Angularjs from Sql Server Database using OOP

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, sql-server-2008

I want to create a class which perform following tasks:

1. We pass any store procedure(for example user select from dropdown )
   and after getting this procedure class generate the html table using
   Angularjs.
2. Paging and sorting also available
3. Same functionality for Chart (highcharts) My second question how to
   pass parameter from QueryString In my scenario User login to
   dashboard and dashboard show selected tab to him according to his
   userid after that he change the color or location of different boxes
   on dashboard and save it to database next time when he login he see
   his last saved setting

Comment: Did you wrote some line of code, at least? Share here, don't be shy :)

Comment: Go to upwork hire a developer I  think that can help you. :)